# How can I get this javascript working?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I put the following JS directly on a site of my WordPress blog.
It should play one of the two audio files randomly if you click on a button.

My question is:

- Is there anything wrong / missing with the JS
- How can I get it started by a button?

```
<script>
var playlist = Array();
playlist.push("http://.../wp-content/uploads/2015/03/xxx.mp3");
playlist.push("...wp-content/uploads/2015/03/10-Good-Evening.mp3");


console.log(getSong()); // Here's your song.

document.getElementById("play").addEventListener("click", playSong);


function playSong(){ 
    var audio = new Audio(getSong());
    audio.play(); 
}

function getSong() {
   return playlist[Math.floor(Math.random() * playlist.length)];
} 

</script>
```

Comment: Works for me. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Answer (score 1):

looks good!

just add this html after your javascript tag

```
<button id="play">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me.
I did this but it still doesn't work.
You can see it here: http://fuba-blog.de/randomizer/

Answer (score 1):

The console shows:

```
Navigated to http://fuba-blog.de/randomizer/
VM83:132 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Navigating to the error shows

```
     <script>
var playlist = Array();
playlist.push("http://fuba-blog.de/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/alaba-button-mp3.mp3");
playlist.push("http://fuba-blog.de/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/alaba-button-mp3.mp3");</p>
<p>console.log(getSong()); // Here's your song.</p>
<p>document.getElementById("play").addEventListener("click", playSong);</p>
<p>function playSong(){ 
    var audio = new Audio(getSong());
    audio.play(); 
}</p>
<p>function getSong() {
   return playlist[Math.floor(Math.random() * playlist.length)];
} </p>
<p></script>
```

You have HTML in your script.

Comment: oh, seems like wordpress put it in automatically. thanks. helped me a lot.